# SKSpriteNode won't position after didBeginContact

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm working with collision detection with SpriteKit and Swift. I have a SKScene that responds to a collision with the didBeginContact function:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {        
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Food && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Head) {
        placeFoodInRandomGridLocation()
    }
}
func placeFoodInRandomGridLocation() {
    let randomX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myGrid.columnCount))
    let randomY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myGrid.rowCount))
    foodSpriteHolder.position = CGPoint(x: colLines[Int(randomX)], y: rowLines[Int(randomY)])
}
```

The problem is that I can easily adjust the position of the foodSpriteHolder before this didBeginContact function fires. It simply will not move the foodSpriteHolder when the placeFoodInRandomGridLocation is called.

It seems like a scope issue. I'm just not sure how to isolate why the position won't update. I can even make the foodSpriteHolder visibility hidden in this flow...So, I know i can access it.

For reference here is how the physics body is setup for the Food class item that is within the foodSpriteHolder:

```
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.size, center: CGPointMake(reducedSize/2, reducedSize/2))
    self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Food
```

Lastly the placeFoodInRandomGridLocation function definitely gets called...The position just won't update.

Thanks for any ideas,
Josh

Comment: Have you printed `randomX`and `randomY` out when `placeFoodInRandomGridLocation` is invoked?

Comment: yes, randomX and randomY totally print out fine each time.

Comment: What about `colLines[Int(randomX)]`?

Comment: colLines[Int(randomX)] works too. i can even hard code those values and it won't update the position.

Comment: now i believe that once you set affectedByGravity to false you can't update the position. that looks to be source of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in this case was to remove the node when the collision is detected:

contact.bodyA.node?.removeFromParent()

Now I can create a new node in a new position. Since affectedByGravity is set to false the node wouldn't update its position.